# normal distribution under special condition

Tags: normal-distribution

> Given independent Gaussian random variables $U\sim N(−1,1)$  and $V\sim N(1,1)$, are the 2-element vector $T=(U+V, U−2V)$ and
>   the variable $$W= U\text{ with 50% chance}, V \text{ with 50% chance}$$
>   also Gaussian? If yes, what is the mean and variance (covariance matrix)?

For simple versions of Gaussian problems like $U+V$ I can easily identify properties, but how to approach forms as above? Like for the vector one, what is the condition for it to be Gaussian random var anyway? And how probability of $U$ and $V$ will affect the identity?

Any suggestions?

Comment: I guess that $U$ and $V$ are independent. If you can deal with $U+V$, then you will have no problems dealing with $T$. Just deal with each coordinate and then find their covariance. 

Concerning $W$, try the following. Sketch the pdf's of $U$ and $V$ and then that of $W$, which is just the mean of the pdf's of $U$ and $V$. See if this looks like a Gaussian density and then try to prove your guess.

Comment: @zhoraster If their independence is just a guess, with your edit you introduced a new assumption into the question. Edits are not supposed to change the question. It would be more appropriate to explain to in a comment why you think they're independent, and then OP can decide whether to add that condition to their question.